# Grant privileges on database names matching a pattern

Tags: mysql

I want to create a mysql user who can only access databases which have names starting with `netdata_`. I use the following statement to create such user:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `netdata_*`.* TO netdata@"%" IDENTIFIED BY "My_Top_Secret";
```

However, with this user `netdata`, I can see nothing other than the `information_schema`. So is there anything wrong in my grant statement? Thanks.

Comment: Nothing in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) leads me to believe that partial patterns would work, nor have I every seen anyone do this. As far as I know, database and table names in a `GRANT` statement are either fully-specified (`netdata_foo`) or global `*`.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. My purpose actually is to not allow the user to access `information_schema`, but to be able to access any databases, including any future created databases. I'm not sure if there is any way to achieve this?